# d3 time format hour adding 7 hours

Tags: javascript, d3.js

I am using d3 to parse a time and it keeps adding 7 hours to the time I try to parse. Why is that? Here is my code:

```
>> var f = d3.time.format("%x %X")
undefined
>> f.parse("10/13/2015 13:59:23")
Date 2015-10-13T20:59:23.000Z
```

Why is it doing this and how do I get it to just parse exactly what I pass in?

I am using this version of d3: `https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/d3/3.5.6/d3.min.js`

Thanks in advance

Comment: See http://bl.ocks.org/jebeck/9671241

Answer (score 1):

`Date 2015-10-13T20:59:23.000Z` is UTC.

I suspect `f.parse("10/13/2015 13:59:23")` is accepting local data. If you're utc-7, then this is most likely the reason, and you should not be concerned about it because, in that case, `Date 2015-10-13T20:59:23.000Z` is equal to `Date 2015-10-13T20:59:23 UTC-7`

Comment: Okay, that makes sense. Can I set my timezone so d3 doesn't try to make this conversion for me?

Comment: @Jeremy according to the doc, `format.parse` returns a date object: https://github.com/mbostock/d3/wiki/Time-Formatting#parse. You're apparently just displaying the object in the console, which leads to this representation. Try `console.log(new Date)` and see the result

Comment: There's no actual convertion, it's just a different timezone representation. By default, `Date.toString()` (plain javascript) uses ISO-8601 format. If you want something different, just use the usual date api: https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Date

Comment: I guess I'll just store it as UTC and then convert it when it's retrieved. Thanks anyways

Comment: @Jeremy try passing your timezone to f.parse("10/13/2015 13:59:23"). But I think you're misunderstanding the problem, the date is correct. The way it's expressed is just a detail. How are you using the date object afterwards? That's the question

Comment: I would like to plot the data on a graph (x-axis being over time). I could just offset the time according to the timezone of the client

Comment: @Jeremy is "10/13/2015 13:59:23" supposed to be utc?

Comment: no, PST. I enter a PST time and it converts it to UTC automatically

Comment: @Jeremy what does `f.parse("10/13/2015 13:59:23").getHours()` return? I don't think it converts anything. `Date` is a Date. `toString()` expresses it in utc, but other methods don't.

Comment: 13. If I set it to a variable h and then call h.getHours() I get 0

Comment: @Jeremy weird. The 13 is what I would expect, because it uses your browser's timezone, not utc. You can work using these api methods to draw the plots on your charts.